# Getting unknown data from SQL Server using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, sqldatareader

I use this code for getting data from SQL Server:

```
    string rootname = "[" + nameroot + "]";
    string retVal = "";

    string constring = "Data Source =(Local);Initial Catalog=Tajari;Integrated Security=True;";

    SqlConnection conobj = new SqlConnection(constring);

    string commandtext = "select distinct " + rootname + " from TBLJobsRootName where MenuId between 1 and " + countroot + "";
    SqlCommand comobj = new SqlCommand(commandtext, conobj);

    conobj.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = comobj.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        //retVal = dr[nameroot].ToString();
    }

    conobj.Close();
```

Now I need this data inserted into a variable or textbox.

The problem is that my values are unknown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

You can use `Index` value.

Try This:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    retVal = dr[0].ToString();
}
```

**Solution 2 :**

You can also use alias name.

```
string commandtext = "select distinct " + rootname + " as myrootname from   
               TBLJobsRootName   where MenuId between 1 and " + countroot + "";
SqlCommand comobj = new SqlCommand(commandtext, conobj);
conobj.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = comobj.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    retVal = dr["myrootname"].ToString();
}
```

**Suggestion:** Your Query is open to *SQL Injection Attacks* i would suggest you to use *Parameterised Queries* to avoid them.

**Solution 3:** Using *Parameterised Queries*

if you want to add all rootname values you need to add all values to List.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
string commandtext = "select distinct "+rootname+" as myrootname from   
               TBLJobsRootName   where MenuId between 1 and @countroot";
SqlCommand comobj = new SqlCommand(commandtext, conobj);

comobj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countroot",countroot);
conobj.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = comobj.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    lis.Add(dr["myrootname"].ToString());
}

//You can retunrn list
```

Comment: @M.Tajari: You need to add items to list, check my edited answer in `solution3`

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi you cannot use a parameter to express a column name. QUOTENAME is the only possibility here